# Span dense set of Hilbert space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space (inner product-Banach space) and $A\subset H$, then $A^\perp = \{0\}$ iff the Spane of $A$ is dense in $H$. We say that a subset $A$ is dense in $H$ if $\forall x \in H$, $x$ is a limit point of $A$, i.e. $\forall r >0, \; \exists a \in A$ s.t $a \in B(x, r)$ (ball of radius r). In this case ($A\subset H$ and the Spane of $A$ is dense in $H$) if I want to prove a proposition on $H$, is it enough to prove it on A, and why?

Comment: Depends on which proposition. For example, $A$ being countable does not imply $H$ is countable. Maybe you should clarify which other propositions you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in general. For example, if we have proposition $P(x): x \in A$, then to prove it for all $x \in H$ it's clearly not enough to prove it just for $x \in A$.

This is true for propositions $P$ s.t. we can show that $\{x | P(x)\}$ is a closed subspace - for example, if $P(x)$ is "linear functional $f$ is continuous in $x$" - becasue if $B$ is closed subspace that contains $A$, then $B = H$.